# phpMyAdmin foreign key drop-down field values

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm using phpmyadmin (`php` & `mysql`) and I'm having a lot of trouble linking the tables using foreign keys.

I'm getting negative values for the field `countyId` (which is the foreign key). However it is linking to my other table fine and it's cascading fine.

When I go to add data there will be a drop box for the `CountyId` and the values look something like this,

```
-1

1-
```

Here is my alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Baronies
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CountyId)
REFERENCES Counties (CountyId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Somehow I don't know whether this is programming related or not. Your SQL statement looks fine. I have no insight into phpmyadmin and concerning this, your question reads more like "how to use the application phpmyadmin".

Comment: This has nothing to do with the query, or the key itself. Your dropdown box for selecting the values doens't have a negative entry, in this case, no matter which one you choose, you will be entering the value '1'. Why pMA represents it in this way; I don't know...

Answer (score 10):

As i explained on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/124787/foreign-key-problem-linking-tables-in-phpmyadmin):

It is not negaitve number, the feature of phpMYAdmin is to show foreign key value and a custom description field next to it. In the referenced table (Counties) you can go to "Relation view" and under the table there is a select box "Choose field to display", in which you choose value that will be displayed next to CountyID value in the referencing table (Baronies). Also see: [phpymadminWiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_6.21)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the look of this dropdown using the `ForeignKeyDropdownOrder` option. (See the [PMA documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/)).

Example:

```
$cfg['ForeignKeyDropdownOrder'] = array( 'content-id');
/* 'content' is the referenced data, 'id' is the key value. */
```

Answer (score 3):

As Lex said, this is just the way phpMyAdmin displays the values.  If you see "-1" or "1-" in that dropdown box, it's just 1.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your tables use MyIsam engine. In that case foreign keys are not supported. Use InnoDB instead.

Comment: Yeah both tables are using InnoDB engine.

Comment: phpmyadmin uses MyIsame by default is there anyway to change this? I've tried looking but haven't found anything.

Cause i've just been changing the tables to InnoDB....could this be the problem?

Comment: The default in mySql is myISAM, this is not a phpmyadmin option.

Check on the MySql documentation about the DB engines at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: To change the default engine use the option default-storage-engine=InnoDB on your my.cnf file

Comment: How is this answer related to the question?

Answer (score -1):

go to operation than change myiasm to innoDB than Go

Comment: I can't make a lot of sense of this, but it doesn't seem to have much to do with foreign keys. Perhaps some more detail would be useful.